# Calling list element in R's c() function

Tags: r

I am rather embarrassed to ask this basic question but I am having trouble calling a list element in the `c()`.

My target output looks like this:

```
FO01-98KF QY85-65GA VO03-93EF 
   "blue"   "green"     "red"
```

Since the "title" characters keep changing depending on my input (this is happening inside a function), I want to make the assignment as general as possible.

```
SeqColor <- c("QY85-65GA","VO03-93EF","FO01-98KF") %>% sort()
ColorSeq <- c(SeqSort[1] = "blue", SeqSort[2] = "green", SeqSort[3] = "red")
```

However, I can't seem to assign the "title" by calling a vector element (the other way around is no problem). This is the warning message I get:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "c(SeqSort[1] ="
```

Sorry for this really basic problem, but if anyone has an idea how I could get to my desired output without calling the elements in SeqColor by their name, I'd really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this as two steps, setting the values then the names:

```
ColorSeq <- c("blue", "green", "red")
names(ColorSeq) <- SeqColor
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setNames`:

```r
setNames(ColorSeq, SeqColor)
#FO01-98KF QY85-65GA VO03-93EF 
#   "blue"   "green"     "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the sorted names to the colors. You can use the following code:

```
ColorSeq <- c("blue", "green", "red")
SeqSort <- c("QY85-65GA","VO03-93EF","FO01-98KF") %>% sort()
names(ColorSeq) <- SeqSort
ColorSeq
```

Output:

```
FO01-98KF QY85-65GA VO03-93EF 
   "blue"   "green"     "red"
```